# How to join two tables in spring hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a web application which uses spring hibernate technology. I have role based accesss control wherein user may have specific roles to access the system. Each user may be assigned to multiple roles. Roles are assigned with multiple permissions. My table structure is given below.

```
role_permission(role_perm_id(PK), role_id(FK), screen_perm_id(FK))
role(role_od(PK),role_name))
screen_perm(screen_perm_id(PK), screen_id(FK), perm_id(FK))
screens(screen_id(PK), screen_name)
permission(perm_id(PK),perm_name)
```

I want to have a view page which displays all permissions of a role. In that page i want to have a checkbox which shows permission. If that permissions is assigned to role then it is checked and if it is not assigned then it is unchecked. How van i do it. Im new to spring hibernate. Pleasw help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Role{
   @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "role",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true)
   Set<Permission> permissions= new HashSet<>();
}
public class Permission {
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   Role role;
}
```

And then you can get the permissions with role.getPermissions();

Comment: Here only the permissions assigned to a role is displayed. I want to display all permissions of all screens for a role. If any permission is assigned to a role that checkbox will be ticket and all other permnissions will be unchecked.